# Broken dropdowns in SQL Server Configuration Manager on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, mmc, sql-server-2012

I recently installed a new virtual VMWare machine for development purposes. The machine has Windows 8.1 (64 bit), Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition, all with latest updates.

Today I wanted to create a new Alias in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. I have previously done this for MS SQL 2012 on Windows 7 and it was straight forward. But on Windows 8.1 I was unpleasantly surprised. All dropdowns in SQL Server Configuration Manager properties are broken - they are narrow and do not display any options. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Broken dropdown for Alias]

I thought that only the Protocol dropdown is broken, but I noticed the same issue with other dropdowns, even for simple Yes/No values:

[image: Broken dropdown for Alias]

I've heard from some people that some programs render broken on Windows 8 (one example was Office Live Meeting which has cropped configuration dialog) but haven't seen something like this before.

I tried to disable 3D rendering for VMWare but that didn't help.

What is wrong with these dropdowns and how do I fix them?

Comment: What version of the configuration manager exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the version of the configuration manager. It was installed with MS SQL Server 2012 with SP1 (full server version number is 11.0.3128.0).

Comment: It is unfortunate that the makers of SQL Server can't be bothered to work more closely with Microsoft to ensure that their products work properly in newer versions of Windows.

Comment: Are you using a "high-dpi" monitor?

Comment: Currently resolution is 1366x768 and I haven't changed any other settings, I left them as they were "out of the box" but I'm not sure what VMWare video drivers did to the system. I asked some of my work colleagues and two of them reported the same problem. In one case it's on Windows 7 64 bit, but this person says that some months ago he didn't have the issue. Maybe some Windows or SQL Server update broke it....

Comment: @BrianAdkins - **SQL Server IS MADE BY MICROSOFT.**  Are you even familar with this program?

Comment: @Martin - I would click on `Help -> About` to provide the information in question.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint. I imagined that Management Console will show only it's own version number but there is it: SQL Server Configuration Manager, Microsoft Corporation, Version: 2011.0110.2100.060

Comment: Now I managed to select values blindly using arrow keys and enter. But it feels so awkward to be unable to see what I'm selecting...

Comment: Try the latest cumulative Update for SQL Server 2012 Sp1: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2931078. Maybe this fixes it.

Comment: @Ramhound : My comment was sarcasm.  Our Dev team here (100% .Net) has been frustrated by broken interface issues in Windows 8+ (High DPI) within Microsoft's own development tools (Visual Studio, SSMS, etc)... hence my follow-up comment regarding high dpi (no answer as of yet).

Comment: Here is an example of Windows 8 High DPI issues within SSMS : http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764009/ssms-does-not-display-properly-in-high-dpi

Comment: I think in my case the problem is not related to DPI because I'm running it on a virtual machine with 1366x768 resolution and DPI setting is on 100%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, see this workaround, here:

[Configuration Manager Snapin dropdownlists are broken: empty and gray](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747902/configuration-manager-snapin-dropdownlists-are-broken-empty-and-gray#).

Choose the **Workarounds (1)** and it reads:

> Do not use the version of SQLServerManager11.msc in the C:\Windows\System32 directory on Windows 2012 64 bit (possibly extended this to any 64-bit OS?) the drop-down boxes are gray and inaccessible for the options.
>
> Instead use the version in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 as it appears to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `cmd` and type `run` and paste the following `cmd` :

```
c:\\Windows\SysWOW64\compmgmt.msc
```

You can configure and the dropdown will be visible.